# oracle sql query and export excel and send email not shown persian and shown as question mark pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle, smtplib

oracle sql query and export excel and send email not shown persian and shown as question marks

```
  connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user_db,password_db,dsn_tns)
  df = pd.read_sql(query,con=connection)
  attach_file_name = filename+'_'+timestr+'.xlsx'
  df.to_excel(attach_file_name,sheet_name="report",encoding="utf-8",engine='xlsxwriter')
  msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
  attach_file = open(attach_file_name,'rb')
  payload = MIMEBase('application','octate-stream')
  payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
  encoders.encode_base64(payload)
  payload.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attach_file; filename= "+attach_file_name)
  msg.attach(payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

it is solved by reading query by encoding utf-8 from cx_orcale and change the engine of excel writer to xlswriter and set encoding

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user_db,password_db,dsn_tns,encoding="UTF-8")
df = pd.read_sql(indict.datasources.Query, con=con)
df.to_excel(attach_file_name, sheet_name="report", encoding="utf-8", engine='xlsxwriter')
```